# replace string doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var base64Data = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ'

var base64ImageContent = base64Data.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");

console.log(base64ImageContent) <-- still the same
```

What's wrong here? replace doesn't work here, where is my mistake?

Comment: (png|jpg) should be (png|jpeg)

Comment: @threadp can I put like `(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)`?

Comment: Yes. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've:

> var base64Data = 'data:image/**jpeg**;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ'

but you're matching:

> var base64ImageContent = base64Data.replace(/^data:image/(png|**jpg**);base64,/, "");

You need to include `jpeg`:

```
var base64ImageContent = base64Data.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg);base64,/, "");
```

Comment: @MariaJane No idea.. someone enraged :) Who downvoted this answer also downvoted your question... I just upvoted it because it's a valid question and on-topic.

Comment: Just doing my part to undo those who don't support the community on SO. Have my upvote

Comment: Probably got DV because this should be closed as a minor typo

Comment: @JordanHendrix Although OP didn't update the question, but this isn't just a typo. See question comments.